# How to pull the latest commit of a PR?

Tags: git, github

I am reviewing someone else's PR from Github. And I have local branch of it. Now the author has another commit for the PR, and I'd like to pull the latest commit to my local branch, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Just do a `git pull` as you normally would for any other branch:

```
git pull origin someBranch
```

Note that when your colleague updated his pull request, he most likely did so by simply updating his branch.  So all you have to do is pull that latest commit into your local branch.